# Customer can change the background colour - Flutter

Tags: flutter, background

I couldn't find any tutorial or even here, any answer for that question.
How can I let the final user change the background colour of the app?
I would like to have a Button as: Background colour. Pop ups a selection list with some colours.
Has anyone able to guimme a guidance please?

Comment: are you trying to show the user different buttons of different colors or different button with colors name and on tapping on the button you want to change the background color?

Answer (score 0):

Create a global colour class and create a variable of type Color like

```
userSelectedColor = Colors.red;
```

Assign this variable to all scaffolds as the background color. You can probably use shared preferences to save the color selected ny the user.. save it as a string (hex) and convert it back when the user opens the app. You can use these methods

```dart
colorToHexString(Color color) {
  return '#FF${color.value.toRadixString(16).substring(2, 8)}';
}


hexStringToColor(String hexColor) {
  hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
  if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
  }
  return Color(int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16));
}
```

Comment: That's far too much work.  Just use aColor.value as a 32-bit int to store, and retrieve it with Color(someInt).  Stop forcing hex in the storage!

Comment: Yeah that's a good suggestion. But saving it as hex is easier to read. Btw saving a string of 6 characters in shared preference isn't going to create a a storage issue i think..

Comment: Why are you reading it raw in the shared preferences?  Do you read other ints in the raw as well?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. If i say colour code FF0000 it means red but for the same color the int value is 4294198070. It's much easier to read FF0000.